# Setting the ng-pattern using set-Attribute is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have following code , where I am creating dynamic elements.

```
commentText.setAttribute("type", "Number");
commentText.setAttribute("min", "0");
commentText.setAttribute("decimal-places", "");
div.appendChild(label);
div1.appendChild(commentText);
div.appendChild(div1);
$compile(div)($scope);
form.appendChild(div);
```

After this,  I am trying to use  a ng-pattern here,

```
commentText.setAttribute('ng-pattern', '/^[0-9]{1,6}$/')
```

And In dom this gets generated

```
<input ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,6}$/"
       class="form-control ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-pattern ng-touched" 
       id="PINCODE" ng-model="PINCODE">
```

So, After this as well this element is not using the ng-pattern and accepting all the values. How can I resolve this ?

Comment: Normally DOM manipulation is done in directives and uses AngularJS [jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angularjs-s-jqlite). Where are you doing this DOM manipulation and why are you using vanilla DOM manipulation instead of jqLite?

Comment: I see that the code adds `type`, `min`, and, `decimal-places` attributes. Why aren't they on the `<input>` element? Is the `ng-pattern` attribute added before or after the $compile?

Comment: Okay Let me check and they are added before $compile.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That code should be… **Complete** – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem.